# In Python 3, how to properly subclass a tuple to create a pair, with proper type hints?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, tuples

Suppose that I would need to subclass the tuple to create a pair of two float numbers. Besides normal tuple functionality, I would like to have properties `.x` and `.y` to access the two values.

I often use PyCharm to do some larger projects, so type hinting is quite essential for me. So I am adding typing information for better maintenance in long term.

Some sample code below:

```
from typing import Tuple

class Pair(Tuple[float, float]):
    def __new__(cls, x: float, y: float):
        pair = super().__new__(cls, (x, y))
        return pair

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self[1]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.x},{self.y})'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Pair(1, 2)
    print(a)
    print(a.x)
    print(a.y)
```

Outputs:

```
(1,2)
1
2
```

But PyCharm keeps warning that

> Expected type 'Type[_T]', got 'Pair' instead.

Is there something wrong with the `__new__` function?

Comment: on which line does the PyCharm warning show?

Comment: PyCharm 2020.2.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-202.6948.78, built on August 25, 2020

Just not sure if this is a syntactic problem or PyCharm problem.

Comment: I meant *where* exactly did it say the warning (which line) not your PyCharm version

Comment: pair = super().__new__(cls, (x, y))

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use ``typing.NamedTuple`` instead?

Comment: And for that matter use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple). It suits your case well and is supported by PyCharms type analyser.